# use cookbook install nginx. compile passenger error

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, passenger, rbenv, cookbook

I use this [nginx cookbook](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx) to install nginx in vagrant.

When run command `knife solo cook user@ip`, i got error below:

```
checking for getaddrinfo() ... found
configuring additional modules
adding module in /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/ext/nginx
*** The Phusion Passenger support files are not yet compiled. Compiling them for you... ***
*** Running 'rake nginx CACHING=false' in /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/ext/nginx... ***
STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/bin/rake:9:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/bin/rake:9
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20141001-14979-2i0uo6" ----
```

It seems `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/rake` make this error. I use `rbenv`, so use `rbenv`'s `rake` is correct. `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/rake` is wrong.

After run:

```
vagrant ssh
cd /path/to/passenger
rake nginx CACHING=false
```

and `knife solo cook user@ip` is success and no error.

My node.json:

```
{
  "run_list": [         
    "recipe[rbenv]",
    "recipe[rbenv::ruby_build]",
    "recipe[install_rbenv_ruby]",
    "recipe[postgresql::server]",
    "recipe[nginx::source]"
  ],
  "rbenv": {
    "group_users": [ "vagrant" ]
  },
  "nginx": {
    "version": "1.4.7",
    "passenger": {
        "version": "4.0.52",
        "gem_binary": "/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/gem",      
      "root": "/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52",
      "ruby": "/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby"
    },
    "source": {
      "modules": [
        "nginx::http_stub_status_module",
        "nginx::http_ssl_module",
        "nginx::http_gzip_static_module",
        "nginx::passenger"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix `rake`'s problem when passenger compile?

I also can add recipe to run passenger comiple, but run complie is spend the very much time. How can i write `not_if` block?

```
bash 'compile_passenger_source' do
  cwd  "/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/ext"
  code <<-EOH
    /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake nginx CACHING=false
  EOH

end
```

Comment: were you able to find solution for this rake's problem

Comment: I add a recipe to run passenger compile after passenger installed. see [my gist](https://gist.github.com/jayhsu21/26de43c00f15cb49f57c#file-compile_passenger_source-rb)

Comment: Thanks jayhsu. I wil refer it..i Really appreciate you response.. Thanks

Comment: /opt/chef/embedded/bin needs to be removed from your PATH.  if chef is adding that, that is probably a bug where we need to be more specific about when and where we add the embedded/bin dir to the PATH

Comment: The Chef binaries are getting added to your shell when you install Chef-DK and add the chef eval command to your .bashrc/.zshrc